# How do I create an Azure Credential that will give access to the WebSiteManagementClient?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, credentials, azure-active-directory, azure-sdk-.net

I want to use the WebSiteManagementClient from the Azure SDK but I'm falling over at the first hurdle - creating the client. I have already created an Active Directory application, following the instructions provided by [David Murray](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-arm-deployment/) and that allowed me to create a TokenCredential which I successfully used to create SQL databases with the SQLManagementClient.

```
ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential("{myApplicationId}", "{myAzurePassword}");
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/{myTennantId}");
var result = context.AcquireToken("https://management.azure.com/", cc);
if (result == null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
TokenCloudCredentials CloudCred = new TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, result.AccessToken);
var sqlClient = new SqlManagementClient(CloudCred);
...
// and this can be used to create databases in resource groups
```

The WebSiteManagementClient seems to need a different set of parameters. First it requires a ServiceClientCredential and then some DelegatingHandlers. Where do I get a ServiceClientCredential? and what are Delegating Handlers. I've looked for a blog with an example of this but without success. I'd very much appreciate any pointers. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Having continued my search I found and answer to a similar problem [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f322781d-a2b6-4793-8c32-1bc04b743408/changes-to-computemanagementclient-constructor?forum=windowsazuremanagement), but this time accessing the ComputeManagementClient. Having tested out the solution there I realised that I was very close. I just needed to create the credential with the result.AccessToken, rather than with the SubscriptionID, as below

```
ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential("{myApplicationId}", "{myAzurePassword}");
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/{myTennantId}");
var result = context.AcquireToken("https://management.azure.com/", cc);
if (result == null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
TokenCredentials Cred = new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken);
var sqlClient = new SqlManagementClient(CloudCred);
...
// and this can be used to create databases in resource groups
```

My thanks to Noah Stahl, who provided the answer there

Comment: When I do as you suggest here I get a PlatformNotSupportedException when trying to use the WebsiteManagmentClient (when creating it).  Every sample I could find requires a certificate but it makes no sense why this would be required. Ideas?